# SharePoint designer workflow mail

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, office-365, designer-workflow

I have a custom list for the approval process.

Once the item is created mean mail should trigger the approver.

**If approver click the item link means he want to approve or reject the item in the in the URL link.**

I created the edit form in the SharePoint. Now how can I add Approve and Reject button on the page for the approval process?

**Note:** I don't want to create in InfoPath form.

anyone can give me suggestions to finish this

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you're using SharePoint 2013 workflow, you could use OOB 'Start a task process' for approval process.

SharePoint will generate the approve/reject task form like below:

[image]

When approver click Approved/Rejected, you could get the result by task outcome,
based on task outcome, do other actions.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SharePoint Online and O365, use Flow for easy notification and approval function.  This is basically replacing the info-path-to-generate-workflow scenario.  From your SPO list, you should have a Flow connector icon; select that and create your approve/reject workflow there. If you're familiar with IFTTT, this is very similar - a number of actions are already created.  Select what you want and you can then customize what happens with your flow. Here's a great [starting point](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/flow/modern-approvals).